# Is there any API for drawing wikipedia pageview data

Tags: api, wikipedia, mashup

How can I get the daily pageview of wikipedia page.

for example, I want to get the history of daily page view of this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming
Is it possible?

Comment: there is this data, http://dammit.lt/wikistats/ but i dont know how to process gz file in PHP (fast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an API for it, but a website exists at [stats.grok.se](http://stats.grok.se/en/201102/Computer_programming) that processes the (very large) files from http://dammit.lt/wikistats/.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new (December 2015) API here: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/?doc

For example, to get the number of views of http://en.wiktionary.org/beauty on 2/12/2015:

```
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/en.wiktionary/all-access/all-agents/beauty/daily/20151202/20151203
```

Response:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "project": "en.wiktionary",
      "article": "beauty",
      "granularity": "daily",
      "timestamp": "2015120200",
      "access": "all-access",
      "agent": "all-agents",
      "views": 34
    }
  ]
}
```

You can also see top 1000 pages on a wiki (`/metrics/pageviews/top/`) and aggregate pageviews on a wiki (`/metrics/pageviews/aggregate/`).

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two new initiatives to build an API around Wikipedia pageviews: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Analytics/Hypercube and http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:GWicke/Notes/Storage. Both are in the planning stage but feel free to chime in with specific use cases.